# Magento with SSL + Varnish

Tags: magento, varnish, magento-1.9

I want to use Varnish on our Magento store to make it faster.
We run CentOS 6.6 with DirectAdmin.

But our entire store always loads on a https connection.

What is the best way to install varnish for our store with SSL?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities. If you have only one server the best way is to install SSL on a NginX and forward the terminated request to Varnish. Varnish can cache the result from the "backend" and deliver them directly to NginX. In most cases you have a Loadbalancer before your setup witch makes the SSL termination and redirect them to varnish.

But you have to be patient, then a lot of sites in a shop can't be cashed because there are dynamic forms.

Here is a good extension to get Varnish work with Magento.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pagecache-powered-by-varnish.html

And here is a good tutorial for SSL:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-varnish-cache-4-0-with-ssl-termination-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I think this works if you set both the unsecure and secure connection to ```https://yoursite```;  if you set to https the secure connection only you'll have a redirect loop since magento receives http (cleaned from https by the first nginx).

Answer (score 1):

Varnish server setup for magento.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/varnish
```

Default configuration replace from

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
-T localhost:6082 \
-f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
-S /etc/varnish/secret \
-s malloc,256m"
```

To

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,1024m"
```

Check default.vcl file port

```
nano /etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

Output-:

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
}
```

Configure the nginx.conf to listen port **8080**.

For More details See My Article [Install Magento2 on Ubuntu (Nginx, Mysql-Server, PHP5.6, Varnish Cache)](http://gotechnies.com/install-magento2-ubuntu-nginx-mysql-server-php5-6-varnish-cache/)

Comment: this is for magento2 while the question is tagged against ver 1.9

Comment: This is working for both Magento versions. I have tested for both versions.